# Accessing the features of a temporary output with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to access the features of a temporary output to save certain geometric properties (in this case the length) in a variable.

Usually I would use:

```py
path="C:\Users\..."
for files in os.listdir(path):
    if files.endswith(".shp"):
        layer = QgsVectorLayer(path+'/'+files, files, "ogr")
        features = layer.getFeatures()
        for f in features:
            geom = f.geometry()
            length = geom.length()
```

But since I'm now working with a temporary layer, created in a previous step in the script, I want to do something like this:

```py
path="C:\Users\..."
for files in os.listdir(path):
    if files.endswith(".shp"):
        output=processing.runalg("qgis:pointstopath",path+'/'+files,"field1","field2","",None,None)
        features = output['OUTPUT_LINE'].getFeatures()
        for f in features:
            geom = f.geometry()
            length = geom.length()
```

How can I access the features of the temporary `output['OUTPUT_LINE']` layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
output = processing.runalg("qgis:pointstopath",path+'/'+files,"field1","field2","",None,None)
layer = processing.getObject(output['OUTPUT'])
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    # do something more
```

Comment: Doesn't work in QGIS3.x

Comment: Have you found a solution of how to do this in QGIS3?